# python how to print a whole line from a csv

Tags: python, csv

if i print this, it returns me the both lists, but i only want it returns 1 of two
i also like it return a randomly list like the first one or the second one, same order
i try with random shuffles, choice, etc, but it returns juts one element but i want the whole list how can i do it

```
#the csv file
numbers, one, two, three, four, five
words, nice, please, computer, television, nouse

#the python file
import csv, random
with open("testing.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as x:
    c = csv.reader(x)
    for line in c:
        print(line)
```

this is what i tried
and it returns
['numbers', ' one', ' two', ' three', ' four', ' five']
['words', ' nice', ' please', ' computer', ' television', ' nouse']

and i only want one of those two

Comment: `for line in c: print(line)` asks Python to print EVERY line in c.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.choice` to select a random element from a list. We can convert `c` to a list, turning it into a list of lines, and then print one of those lines randomly.

```py
import csv, random
with open("testing.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as x:
    c = csv.reader(x)
    lines = list(c)
    print(random.choice(lines))
```